# Adding element in sorted order in an array

Tags: c

I want to add the element in an array while entering it in a sorted manner. That means at the time of entering the new element in array, it will add its sorted state.

I have tried following examples, but I want to do it in an automatic manner. Can anyone help me, please?

my example

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int a[20], n, item, i;

    printf("Enter the size of the array");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    printf("Enter elements of the array in the sorted order");
    for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }

    printf("\nEnter ITEM to be inserted : ");
    scanf("%d", &item);

    i = n - 1;
    while (item<a[i] && i >= 0)
    {
        a[i + 1] = a[i];
        i--;
    }
    a[i + 1] = item;
    n++;

    printf("\n\nAfter insertion array is :\n");
    for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("\n%d", a[i]);
    }
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Please tag your post appropriatly, this looks like C syntax, not Basic

Comment: Thanks Brad for reply, yes i am doing simple assignment in C.

Comment: Looks like you want [std::set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/) or you can roll your own implementation as [suggested here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20222891/insert-into-sorted-array)

Comment: he's asking you to remove the "basic" tag, basic is a completely separate programming language from C. @Brad The post isn't tagged C++ :/ and looking at the code, I doubt `std::set` is an option.

Comment: Sure, I posted my comment before the tag change to `C` only. Have posted a potential solution now

Comment: The code you've posted works, so if it doesn't solve your problem then I guess I don't understand what you mean by an "automatic manner".

Comment: Thanks all, i got the solution, @john automatic manner means i mean to say, it has to be inserted in sorted array order before putting in array, i.e check the position and put it in.